# Sql server Pivot, Joining 4 tables and Group By

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I am trying to produce the following:

```
Product Name | Color | 40 | 41 | 42 | 43 | 44 |
-----------: | ------|---:|--: |--: |---:|---:|
 COOL99-3    | Black | 70 |  1 | 71 | 16 | 30 |
 COOL99-3    | Brown | 20 | 50 | 80 | 20 | 15 |
 COOL99-12   | Black | 23 | 12 | 19 | 25 | 45 |
 COOL99-12   | Brown | 09 | 16 | 07 | 34 | 55 |
 COOL99-81   | Black | 14 | 13 | 23 | 06 | 13 |
 COOL99-81   | Brown | 18 | 19 | 48 | 20 | 15 |
```

I have this tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Product](
    [PID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ProductCode] [nchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [ProductName] [nchar](200) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [CostPrice] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [SellingPrice] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [Discount] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [VAT] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [Barcode] [nchar](30) NULL,
    [ReorderPoint] [int] NOT NULL,
    [OpeningStock] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Color] [nchar](150) NULL,
    [CategoryName] [nchar](150) NULL,
    [SizeID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Product] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Invoice_Product](
    [IPo_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [InvoiceID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ProductID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CostPrice] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [SellingPrice] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [Margin] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [Qty] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Amount] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [DiscountPer] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [Discount] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [VATPer] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [VAT] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [TotalAmount] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [Barcode] [nchar](30) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Invoice_Product] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
)


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[InvoiceInfo](
    [Inv_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [InvoiceNo] [nchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [InvoiceDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [CustomerID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SalesmanID] [int] NULL,
    [GrandTotal] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [TotalPaid] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [Balance] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [Remarks] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_InvoiceInfo] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
)


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customer](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CustomerID] [nchar](30) NULL,
    [Name] [nchar](200) NULL,
    [Gender] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [Address] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [City] [nchar](200) NULL,
    [State] [nchar](150) NULL,
    [ZipCode] [nchar](15) NULL,
    [ContactNo] [nchar](150) NULL,
    [EmailID] [nchar](200) NULL,
    [Remarks] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Photo] [image] NULL,
    [CustomerType] [nchar](30) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Customer] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
)
```

With this query I can't goup by:

```
declare @d1 as varchar(50)='PB-0005';
WITH Sales as(
SELECT      
                      Product.ProductName, Product.CategoryName, tblSize.Size,  Product.Color,Invoice_Product .Qty 
FROM         Customer INNER JOIN
                      InvoiceInfo ON Customer.ID = InvoiceInfo.CustomerID INNER JOIN
                      Invoice_Product ON InvoiceInfo.Inv_ID = Invoice_Product.InvoiceID INNER JOIN
                      Product ON Invoice_Product.ProductID = Product.PID INNER JOIN
                      tblSize ON Product.SizeID = tblSize.SizeID
WHERE     (InvoiceInfo.InvoiceNo = @d1)  )
SELECT * 
FROM
   Sales  
   PIVOT (sum(Qty) FOR Size IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[7C],[8C],[9C],[10C],[11C],[12C],[13C],[40],[41],[42],[43],[44],[45]))AS P GROUP BY ProductName 
;
```

Comment: MS SQLSERVER 2008

Answer (score 1):

Well, given the SQL you've provided, the following issues will be a problem:

1. The table creation statements don't work, since you didn't provide a column name. I assumed that the column name should be the first column from each table.
2. You didn't provide the command to create `tblSize`. I created one with just `SizeID` (`IDENTITY` column, and primary key) and `Size`.
3. Your main SELECT failed because you don't need a `GROUP BY` clause with the `PIVOT` statement; it automatically groups by the columns you include in the `SELECT` list that aren't a part of the `PIVOT` itself.
4. `Customer` is unnecessary in your CTE, as you are not using any values from that table (at least in this example - you might need to add it back in if you did want to use some of its columns). (Not actually a problem, just an unnecessary complication to the query)

Below is the code I tested. It's got the corrections for the items I've noted above. It also has test data (which certainly may not match your data, but you provided none). I trimmed down the list of sizes to be returned to those you showed in your example. I'm using an equation to generate the quantities in the invoice in question (to save some time), so the quantities do not match your example.

Here's my SQL:

```
use tempdb;

IF (OBJECT_ID('Product') IS NOT NULL) DROP TABLE Product;
IF (OBJECT_ID('Invoice_Product') IS NOT NULL) DROP TABLE Invoice_Product;
IF (OBJECT_ID('InvoiceInfo') IS NOT NULL) DROP TABLE InvoiceInfo;
IF (OBJECT_ID('Customer') IS NOT NULL) DROP TABLE Customer;
IF (OBJECT_ID('tblSize') IS NOT NULL) DROP TABLE tblSize;

CREATE TABLE [Product](
    [PID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ProductCode] [nchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [ProductName] [nchar](200) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [CostPrice] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [SellingPrice] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [Discount] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [VAT] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [Barcode] [nchar](30) NULL,
    [ReorderPoint] [int] NOT NULL,
    [OpeningStock] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Color] [nchar](150) NULL,
    [CategoryName] [nchar](150) NULL,
    [SizeID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Product] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([PID])
);

CREATE TABLE [Invoice_Product](
    [IPo_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [InvoiceID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ProductID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CostPrice] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [SellingPrice] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [Margin] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [Qty] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Amount] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [DiscountPer] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [Discount] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [VATPer] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [VAT] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [TotalAmount] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [Barcode] [nchar](30) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Invoice_Product] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([IPo_ID])
);


CREATE TABLE [InvoiceInfo](
    [Inv_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [InvoiceNo] [nchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [InvoiceDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [CustomerID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SalesmanID] [int] NULL,
    [GrandTotal] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [TotalPaid] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [Balance] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [Remarks] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_InvoiceInfo] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Inv_ID])
);


CREATE TABLE [Customer](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CustomerID] [nchar](30) NULL,
    [Name] [nchar](200) NULL,
    [Gender] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [Address] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [City] [nchar](200) NULL,
    [State] [nchar](150) NULL,
    [ZipCode] [nchar](15) NULL,
    [ContactNo] [nchar](150) NULL,
    [EmailID] [nchar](200) NULL,
    [Remarks] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Photo] [image] NULL,
    [CustomerType] [nchar](30) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Customer] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID])
);


CREATE TABLE [tblSize](
    [SizeID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Size] [nvarchar](30) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tblSize] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([SizeID])
);

INSERT INTO Customer (ID, CustomerID) VALUES (1, 'Cust1'),(2, 'Cust2');
INSERT INTO tblSize (SizeID, Size)
VALUES (40, '40')
      ,(41, '41')
      ,(42, '42')
      ,(43, '43')
      ,(44, '44')
      ,(45, '45')
;

INSERT INTO Product ([PID], ProductCode, ProductName, CategoryName, Color, SizeID, CostPrice, SellingPrice, VAT, ReorderPoint, OpeningStock, Discount)
VALUES (101, 'COOL99-3' , 'COOL99-3' ,'Thingy','BLACK','40', 5, 10, 1, 1000, 10000,0)
      ,(102, 'COOL99-3' , 'COOL99-3' ,'Thingy','BROWN','40', 5, 10, 1, 1000, 10000,0)
      ,(103, 'COOL99-3' , 'COOL99-3' ,'Thingy','BLACK','41', 5, 10, 1, 1000, 10000,0)
      ,(104, 'COOL99-3' , 'COOL99-3' ,'Thingy','BROWN','41', 5, 10, 1, 1000, 10000,0)
      ,(105, 'COOL99-3' , 'COOL99-3' ,'Thingy','BLACK','42', 5, 10, 1, 1000, 10000,0)
      ,(106, 'COOL99-3' , 'COOL99-3' ,'Thingy','BROWN','42', 5, 10, 1, 1000, 10000,0)
      ,(107, 'COOL99-3' , 'COOL99-3' ,'Thingy','BLACK','43', 5, 10, 1, 1000, 10000,0)
      ,(108, 'COOL99-3' , 'COOL99-3' ,'Thingy','BROWN','43', 5, 10, 1, 1000, 10000,0)
      ,(109, 'COOL99-3' , 'COOL99-3' ,'Thingy','BLACK','44', 5, 10, 1, 1000, 10000,0)
      ,(110, 'COOL99-3' , 'COOL99-3' ,'Thingy','BROWN','44', 5, 10, 1, 1000, 10000,0)
      ,(201, 'COOL99-12', 'COOL99-12','Thingy','BLACK','40', 5, 10, 1, 1000, 10000,0)
      ,(202, 'COOL99-12', 'COOL99-12','Thingy','BROWN','40', 5, 10, 1, 1000, 10000,0)
      ,(203, 'COOL99-12', 'COOL99-12','Thingy','BLACK','41', 5, 10, 1, 1000, 10000,0)
      ,(204, 'COOL99-12', 'COOL99-12','Thingy','BROWN','41', 5, 10, 1, 1000, 10000,0)
      ,(205, 'COOL99-12', 'COOL99-12','Thingy','BLACK','42', 5, 10, 1, 1000, 10000,0)
      ,(206, 'COOL99-12', 'COOL99-12','Thingy','BROWN','42', 5, 10, 1, 1000, 10000,0)
      ,(207, 'COOL99-12', 'COOL99-12','Thingy','BLACK','43', 5, 10, 1, 1000, 10000,0)
      ,(208, 'COOL99-12', 'COOL99-12','Thingy','BROWN','43', 5, 10, 1, 1000, 10000,0)
      ,(209, 'COOL99-12', 'COOL99-12','Thingy','BLACK','44', 5, 10, 1, 1000, 10000,0)
      ,(210, 'COOL99-12', 'COOL99-12','Thingy','BROWN','44', 5, 10, 1, 1000, 10000,0)
      ,(301, 'COOL99-81', 'COOL99-81','Thingy','BLACK','40', 5, 10, 1, 1000, 10000,0)
      ,(302, 'COOL99-81', 'COOL99-81','Thingy','BROWN','40', 5, 10, 1, 1000, 10000,0)
      ,(303, 'COOL99-81', 'COOL99-81','Thingy','BLACK','41', 5, 10, 1, 1000, 10000,0)
      ,(304, 'COOL99-81', 'COOL99-81','Thingy','BROWN','41', 5, 10, 1, 1000, 10000,0)
      ,(305, 'COOL99-81', 'COOL99-81','Thingy','BLACK','42', 5, 10, 1, 1000, 10000,0)
      ,(306, 'COOL99-81', 'COOL99-81','Thingy','BROWN','42', 5, 10, 1, 1000, 10000,0)
      ,(307, 'COOL99-81', 'COOL99-81','Thingy','BLACK','43', 5, 10, 1, 1000, 10000,0)
      ,(308, 'COOL99-81', 'COOL99-81','Thingy','BROWN','43', 5, 10, 1, 1000, 10000,0)
      ,(309, 'COOL99-81', 'COOL99-81','Thingy','BLACK','44', 5, 10, 1, 1000, 10000,0)
      ,(310, 'COOL99-81', 'COOL99-81','Thingy','BROWN','44', 5, 10, 1, 1000, 10000,0)
;

INSERT INTO InvoiceInfo (Inv_ID, InvoiceNo, InvoiceDate, CustomerID, GrandTotal, TotalPaid, Balance)
VALUES (1, 'PB-0005',GETDATE(),1,1000,1000,0)
;

INSERT INTO Invoice_Product ( InvoiceID, ProductID, CostPrice, SellingPrice, Margin, Qty
                             ,Amount, DiscountPer, Discount, VATPer, VAT, TotalAmount)
SELECT h.Inv_ID, p.PID, p.CostPrice, p.SellingPrice, p.SellingPrice - p.CostPrice, ((p.PID * 17 * (p.SizeID - 39)) % 29) + 1
      ,(((p.PID * 17 * (p.SizeID - 39)) % 29) + 1) * p.SellingPrice, 0, 0, 0, 0, (((p.PID * 17 * (p.SizeID - 39)) % 29) + 1) * p.SellingPrice
  FROM InvoiceInfo h
         CROSS JOIN Product p
;

declare @d1 as varchar(50)='PB-0005';
WITH Sales as
     (SELECT      
             Product.ProductName
            ,Product.CategoryName
            ,Product.Color
            ,tblSize.Size
            ,Invoice_Product.Qty 
        FROM InvoiceInfo
               INNER JOIN Invoice_Product ON InvoiceInfo.Inv_ID = Invoice_Product.InvoiceID
                 INNER JOIN Product ON Invoice_Product.ProductID = Product.PID
                   INNER JOIN tblSize ON Product.SizeID = tblSize.SizeID
       WHERE InvoiceInfo.InvoiceNo = @d1
     )
SELECT ProductName, Color, [40],[41],[42],[43],[44]
  FROM Sales PIVOT (sum(Qty)
                    FOR Size IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[7C],[8C],[9C],[10C],[11C],[12C],[13C],[40],[41],[42],[43],[44],[45])
                   ) AS P
;
```

And, here's the results I get:

```
ProductName    Color  40   41   42   43   44
-------------- ------ ---- ---- ---- ---- ----
COOL99-12      BLACK  25   1    16   12   18
COOL99-12      BROWN  13   6    9    22   16
COOL99-3       BLACK  7    23   20   27   15
COOL99-3       BROWN  24   28   13   8    13
COOL99-81      BLACK  14   8    12   26   21
COOL99-81      BROWN  2    13   5    7    19
```